# c++ function definition in the argument of a function

Tags: c++, function, arguments

i recently came across a part of code which looks like as follows:

```
static typename handle_set::iterator find(T* p)
        {
        return std::find_if(handles().begin(), handles().end(), [p](const std::unique_ptr<T,D>& l) { return l.get() == p; });
        }
```

where

```
typedef typename std::set<std::unique_ptr<T,D>> handle_set;
    static handle_set& handles(void)
    {
        static handle_set h_;

        return h_;
    }
```

my question is about this part:

`[p](const std::unique_ptr<T,D>& l) { return l.get() == p; }`

which is the 3rd argument of the function `std::find_if()`. The 3rd argument can be a function pointer. Is this a inline way of defining a function pointer in the argument of another function ? I haven't seen this type of usage before. Is my understanding correct ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::find_if` is templated and accepts as third argument a generic *functor* (also known as "function object"), which is whatever can be called as a function. This class of "things" includes function pointers, any object that overloads the function call operator and lambdas.

In this specific case, you are seeing it used with a lambda function, which is an anonymous function defined in place.

Lambdas are not just "a way to define a function pointer"; instead, they create a *function object* "on the fly" with the given code and captured context. A key difference between lambdas and "regular functions" is the fact that lambdas can capture a context (the variable `p` in your example).

Also, pointers to functions with the same signature have the same type, while lambdas have unspecified type. Still, a lambda that doesn't capture anything converts implicitly to an ordinary function pointer (see C++11 §5.1.2/6, *thanks at [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) for pointing this out*); this makes them useful to use even with functions that accept only function pointers and not generic functors.

You probably haven't seen lambdas around yet because they are a recent addition to the C++ language (they have been standardized in the C++11 standard, approved just this year).

Comment: Lamdas can be used to define function pointers. A lambda that doesn't capture anything *converts implicitly* to function pointer. Well, except with Visual C++ 2010, that is.

Comment: if i have to rewrite the 3rd argument without the c++11 standard in visual studio 2008 can you please give some pointer as to how to go about it.

Comment: can something like the below work as the 3rd argument :std::find_if(handles().begin(), handles().end(), equalto(p));                      where        class equalto 
      {
        public:
        const T* testValue;
        equalto(T* x) : testValue(x) { }

        bool operator()(T* val) const 
        { return val == testValue; }
  };

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: are you sure? I checked [expr.prim.lambda]
in the N3242 standard draft, but I found nothing about lambda to function pointer conversion.

Comment: @user1612986: sure, although you could as well use `std::equal_to` plus `std::bind1st` (if restricted to C++98/C++03).

Comment: @Matteo: I can't for the life of me see anything in my statement that indicated opinion as opposed to fact. Anyway, I just fixed your answer. No point of spending more time on this.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I wasn't questioning your knowledge of the matter (especially because I didn't have time yet to get a good grasp about the C++11 additions), I just didn't find a standard reference because I was using a wrong search term ("function pointer" instead of "pointer to function"). Anyway, thank you both for fixing my answer and for pointing me to the relevant standard passage.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd argument is not a function pointer. It is a function *object*. That object may happen to be a pointer. But it might not. It may be any value which has `operator()`. A lambda is such a value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a C++11 lambda (anonymous function).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've found some C++11 code. You're dealing with a few things there:

1. [Lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)
2. [Unique Pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)
3. [Closures](http://www.cpprocks.com/wp-content/uploads/c++11-rocks-series-free-sample-lambdas.pdf)

You need to do some reading up to understand exactly what that code does.